# Which hybrid apps does Huawei Mobile Services support?

Tags: cordova, flutter, xamarin, hybrid-mobile-app, huawei-mobile-services

Is anyone aware if there exists/are plans to enable deployment for JavaScript/hybrid apps on Huawei Mobile Services (HMS)? Similarly as we can do it using Cordova/Capacitor with Ionic/NativeScript/React Native and upload on Android/iOS.

So far I've been checking https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/community/codelabs and it looks currently only Java is supported without any extra information about hybrid mobile apps. Does anyone has experience with HMS already?

Comment: Did you find anything useful? Such as creating your own cordova plugin?

Comment: @Pierre not yet.

Comment: Thank you. Do you use Capacitor? Because it looks like it is necessary to be able to implement Google Firebase Push notifications. https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/guides/push-notifications-firebase/  You end up with a capacitor android solution as well as ios solution in your ionic project where you have to place the Google-services.json file and that is also where you get your apk generated from. So I reckon you just implement HMS in the same solution as per normal HMS/Java implementation. But then somehow have to modify Capacitor to also include HMS. (I haven't done this, 1st time)

Comment: @Pierre I haven't gone into the process of deploying an app yet to be very honest. First wanted to ask others if anyone tried, because I couldn't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Huawei has provided some HMS Core kit plugins for React Native, Cordova and Xamarin. HMS Core 4.0.4 has been released to support Flutter In June 2020.
Reference documents:
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/overview/HMS-Core-Plugin

**Update**

The HMS Core 5.0.0 version is launched, and the number of Kits supported by third-party platform plug-ins has been increased.
The specific support status is as follows:

***Apache Cordova**

[Account Kit plugins for Cordova](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001051006397)

[Ads Kit plugins for Cordova](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050437673)

[Analytics Kit plugin for Cordova](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050134725)

[AR Engine plugin for Cordova](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001059697332)

[Awareness Kit plugin for Cordova](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001064365517)

[Contact Shield plugin for Cordova](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001071927875)

[Dynamic Tag Manager plugin for Cordova](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001059610277)

[Health Kit plugin for Cordova](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/about-huawei-health-kit-0000001074479470)

[Huawei Availability plugin for Cordova](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001133045241)

[In-App Purchases Kit plugin for Cordova](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001126692133)

[Location Kit plugin for Cordova](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050140246)

[Map Kit plugins for Cordova](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050329204)

[ML Kit plugins for Cordova](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050765773)

[Nearby Service plugins for Cordova](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001062870688)

[Push Kit plugin for Cordova](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050135701)

[Safety Detect plugin for Cordova](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001055426855)

[Scan Kit plugin for Cordova](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001057398487)

[Site Kit plugins for Cordova](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050260022)

***React Native**

[Account Kit plugins for React Native](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001051086206)

[Ads Kit plugins for React Native](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050196714)

[Analytics Kit plugin for React Native](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050157956)

[AR Engine plugin for React Native](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001058619842)

[Awareness Kit plugin for React Native](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001073966243)

[Contact Shield plugin for React Native](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001062825580)

[Dynamic Tag Manager plugin for React Native](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/about-the-service-0000001055654101)

[Health Kit plugin for React Native](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050155802)

[HMS Availability plugin for React Native](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/about-0000001137975023)

[In-App Purchases Kit plugin for React Native](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050766239)

[Location Kit plugin for React Native](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050142177)

[Map Kit plugin for React Native](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050143001)

[ML Kit plugins for React Native](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050726178)

[Native Nearby plugins for React Native](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/about-the-service-0000001053940431)

[Push Kit plugin for React Native](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050157787)

[Safety Detect plugin for React Native](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001053475348)

[Scan Kit plugins for React Native](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001057136450)

[Site Kit plugins for React Native](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050176404)

***Xamarin**

[Account Kit plugins for Xamarin](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050725712)

[Ads Kit plugins for Xamarin](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/service-introduction-0000001050178531)

[Analytics Kit plugins for Xamarin](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050139636)

[AR Engine plugins for Xamarin](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001059257484)

[Awareness Kit plugins for Xamarin](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/service-introduction-0000001062540020)

[Contact Shield plugins for Xamarin](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-overview-0000001061074075)

[Drive Kit plugins for Xamarin](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001077902368)

[Dynamic Tag Manager plugins for Xamarin](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001056706664)

[FIDO plugins for Xamarin](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001096825937)

[Health Kit plugins for Xamarin](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/health-introduce-0000001073349887)

[In-App Purchases plugins for Xamarin](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050727490)

[Map Kit plugins for Xamarin](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050143021)

[ML Kit plugins for Xamarin](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/about-service-0000001052602130)

[Location Kit plugins for Xamarin](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050142217)

[Nearby Service plugins for Xamarin](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001062477568)

[Push Kit plugins for Xamarin](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/service-introduction-0000001095249203)

[Safety Detect plugins for Xamarin](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001058130307)

[Scan Kit plugins for Xamarin](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001057554169)

[Site Kit plugins for Xamarin](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050135801)

[Wallet Kit plugins for Xamarin](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/service-introduction-0000001078418878)

***Flutter**

[Account Kit plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050766441)

[Ads Kit plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/publisher-service-0000001050196431)

[Analytics Kit plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050169136)

[AR Engine plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001058897997)

[Awareness Kit plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001074110480)

[Contact Shield plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001062844379)

[Drive Kit plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001077725482)

[Dynamic Tag Manager plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001061766543)

[FIDO plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001096579081)

[Game Service plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001080980430)

[Health Kit plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/service-introduction-0000001073951368)

[HMS Availability plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001128351789)

[In-App Purchases Kit plugin for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001051001685)

[Location Kit plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050191280)

[Map Kit plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050296908)

[ML Kit plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001051432503)

[Nearby Service plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001074107546)

[Push Kit plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050176002)

[Safety Detect plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001061296565)

[Scan Kit plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001054309573)

[Site Kit plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050181259)

[Wallet Kit plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/service-introduction-0000001096846895)

For more details,check [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides-V1/rn-intro-0000001050975015?ha_source=hms1).

Comment: The HMS' docs seems to be providing the best developer experience in contrast to Apple & Google, I'm so impressed how fast they pace. I'm gonna to re(accept) the answer, because this one is more in detail.

Comment: Update: unbelievable they were able to do so in such a quick time!

Comment: Yes,and please feel free to contact me if you need any further help. :)

Answer (score 3):

referring to developer web site of HMS, they are now officially supporting Location, Push, Analytics and In-App Purchase; Map and Ads are on the way

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/location-integrating-cordova-sdk-v4
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/analytics-integrating-cordova-sdk-v4
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/push-integrating-cordova-sdk
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/iap-integrating-cordova-sdk-v4