# Firestore dependencies in Huawei developer console

Tags: flutter, firebase, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery-connect

I need to release an app that can be downloaded from Huawei's App Gallery .

This would be my first time working in Huawei Developer Console .

I am using Flutter and have an existing app .

I understand that Google Mobile Services wont work .

Is there any guidance or docs to alter Flutter code to achieve same app functionality .

I am using below Firebase dependencies :

firebase_messaging: ^11.4.2
firebase_core: ^1.18.0
cloud_firestore: ^3.1.14
firebase_database: ^9.0.16
firebase_auth: ^3.3.20

Any guidance on this would be much appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the list you provided, you use these GMS services:

> firebase_messaging: ^11.4.2 firebase_core: ^1.18.0 cloud_firestore: ^3.1.14 firebase_database: ^9.0.16 firebase_auth: ^3.3.20

You can refer to the following **Huawei mobile services(HMS)**:

[Push Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-pushkit?ha_source=hms1)、[Account Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-accountkit?ha_source=hms1)、[AppGallery Connect Cloud DB](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/agconnect/cloud-base?ha_source=hms1) 、[AppGallery Connect auth service](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/agconnect/auth-service/?ha_source=hms1)、[AppGallery Connect Cloud Storge](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/agconnect/cloud-storage/?ha_source=hms1)

Huawei also has provided some plugins for Flutter:

[Push Kit plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050176002?ha_source=hms1)、
[Account Kit plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050766441?ha_source=hms1)、
[Cloud DB plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-clouddb-flutter-usage-0000001154073689)、
[Cloud Storge for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-storage-flutter-usage-0000001171821730)、
[Auth service for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-auth-flutter-usage-0000001063724847)

*Similar SO question*:

[Can a Flutter app be proposed on the Huawei AppGallery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59346141/13329100)

[What google services are banned in Harmony OS (here is a list that I have used in my android app.)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63336006/13329100)

[Which hybrid apps does Huawei Mobile Services support?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59231196/13329100)

The following repo contains the source code for HMS Flutter first-party plugin and AGC flutter-plugin Demos, kindly refer:

https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-flutter-plugin

https://github.com/AppGalleryConnect/agc-flutter-plugin

Comment: Thanks . So from a Database point of view  . Can it still be setup to achieve results on all 3 mobiles with HMS integration ? Example : Sending data to DB on Android mobile , iOS mobile and HUAWEI mobile using lets say Firebase DB . Or do i need to create brand new DB from HUAWEI Console ?

Comment: On the no-GMS device, you can still use the firebase DB. It can still work properly on the HMS device.

Comment: I guess i will just have to do a lot of reading , with trail and error integration . Thank you

Comment: If you have any queries, please feel free to contact us back.